# Перегрузка функции по возвращаемому значению в C

Tags: c, функции, ввод

Столкнулся с проблемой, что у мне нужно написать много экземпляров одной функции, которые различаются только возвращаемым значением. Что-то вроде:

```
__uint16_t get_uint(){
    char input[256];
    __uint16_t n;
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    while (sscanf(input, "%u", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Неверный ввод! Попробуйте ещё раз: ");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    }
    return n;
}

__uint32_t get_uint(){
    char input[256];
    __uint32_t n;
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    while (sscanf(input, "%u", &n) != 1) {
        printf("Неверный ввод! Попробуйте ещё раз: ");
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Я знаю, что перегружать функции по значению нельзя, но видел, что в C++ эту проблему можно решить с помощью шаблонов, но в C их нет. Есть ли какой-то другой способ?
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Перегрузка функций в С — ну разве что через дженерик макросы, но и при них все равно надо создавать разные функции, подставляемые вместо одного и того же имени, если я верно понимаю, но отличающиеся только по возвращаемому типу? Например, у вас есть `int f()` и `char f()` — и что делать при `double в = а()`?... Не говорю уж просто о `f()`.

Comment: Это С++ не позволяет перегрузку функций по возвращаемому значению. С не позволяет перегрузку в принципе. Делайте для каждой функции уникальное имя, `get_uint16` `get_uint32`.

Comment: Только имейте в виду, что любая перегрузка функций это потеря контроля над кодом, а это зло.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Шаблоны были всегда. Делались с помощью макросов. Вы ошибаетесь, что функции отличаются только возвращаемым значением. Кроме типа внутренней переменной ещё нужно подправить строку идентификации типа для функции `sscanf`.

Вот как в Си выглядит ваш шаблон :

```
# include <stdio.h>

// .h
# define  FUN_GET_UINT( N ) get_uint_ ## N
# define  DECLARE_GET_UINT( N , T ) T FUN_GET_UINT ( N ) ();
DECLARE_GET_UINT ( ui32 , __uint32_t  )
DECLARE_GET_UINT ( ui16 , __uint16_t  )

// .c
# define  DEFINE_GET_UINT( N , T , S ) \
T FUN_GET_UINT ( N ) (){  \
    char input[256];  \
    T n; \
    fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin); \
    while (sscanf(input, S , &n) != 1) {  \
        printf("Неверный ввод! Попробуйте ещё раз: ");  \
        fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin); \
    } \
    return n; \
}

DEFINE_GET_UINT ( ui32 , __uint32_t ,  "%u" )
DEFINE_GET_UINT ( ui16 , __uint16_t ,  "%hu" )

// main.c
int main(){
  __uint32_t  u32 = FUN_GET_UINT ( ui32 ) ( ) ;
  __uint16_t  u16 = FUN_GET_UINT ( ui16 ) ( ) ;
  }
```